# How to join the main thread to a thread pool in java

Tags: java, multithreading, join, threadpool, executorservice

Like joining two threads using join(), is there a way to join a thread to a ExecutorService object (a thread pool) ?

Comment: You might have to give more context... do you want to wait for a task in the pool to complete? calling get on the future would do that. or is it that you want to co-ordinate two threads in the pool (not sure why you'd want to do that)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), you could, from your second thread, call the shutdown method of your executor service and next, call for awaitTermination. This method will block till completion of all submitted jobs in the executor service.